# How to create json file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, json, file

I need to create a json file with data and store that file in specific directory of magento 2. Can any one please tell me how we can achieve this in magento2 in standard way like file system.

Please don't suggest PHP way as this might not be the standard way due to which magento will restrict module from uploading.

any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;


protected $filesystem;

protected $jsonDir;

public function __construct(
    ...
    Filesystem $filesystem,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
    $this->jsonDir=$filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    ....
}
```

So now prepare your `JSON` content and write to directory,

```
$this->jsonDir->writeFile($relativePath, $content);
```

Where `$relativePath` is relative path of of file and `$content` is your `JSON` content.

Comment: Sorry but it gives Unknown directory type: 'myFiles'

Comment: Updated the answer :) @AshishMadankar

Comment: Thanks for this update but what if i want to create my own directory on root and what do you think about the code which i posted in answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a correct way of implementing but i find this in core file of magento `\vendor\magento\framework\Code\GeneratedFiles.php`

Please suggest on this.

```
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteFactory;

/**
 * @var WriteInterface
 */
prtected $write;

public function __construct(
    ...
    WriteFactory $writeFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->write = $writeFactory->create(BP);
    ....
}
```

And for file creation below code in method.

```
$this->write->writeFile($relativePath, $content);
```

If it is correct then hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

As @Keyur Shah wrote, just add third parameter $mode = 'w' like this

```
$this->jsonDir->writeFile($relativePath, $content, $mode = 'w');
```